# List reverse in particular range

Tags: python, list, recursion, reverse

I wanted to recursively reverse elements in the list for range `i` to `j`.

```
def revlist(l, i, j):
    if not l: # this will be true if l == []
        return l
    return l[-1:] + revlist(l[:-1]) # recursive case
```

For example list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` for `i = 2` and `j = 5` will be `[1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

How to do this?

Comment: Since this is way more complicated and inefficient, why would you want to "*recursively* reverse elements"? This is not at all something you'd want to do recursively, unless you're talking about reversing sublists as well (which your code shows no indication of)

Comment: when you say _recursively_, should an initial subset `[1,2,3,4,5]` be reversed `[5,4,3,2,1]` (no recursion needed) or something more exotic like `[5,2,3,4,1]` (successive calls reverse inner subset)

Comment: what is the use of i and j in `revlist`'s arguments? perhaps they are redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a recursive implementation (which is inefficient, and rather pointless in this use case, as well as limiting the size of the list that can be reversed):

```
def rev_sublist(xs, i, j):
    def rec_rev(ys):
        if not ys:
            return ys
        else:
            return [ys[-1]] + rec_rev(ys[:-1])
    return xs[:i] + rec_rev(xs[i:j]) + xs[j:]


print(rev_sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, 5))
```

If you don't like the idea of the inner function here, the logic will become very convoluted, something like:

```
def rev_sublist(xs, i, j):
    if i >= j:
        return xs
    else:
        return rev_sublist(xs[:i] + [xs[j-1]] + xs[i:j-1] + xs[j:], i+1, j)


print(rev_sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, 5))
```

But if this was a programming class and I asked you to write a routine to reverse lists and you came up with this, I'm about to fail you.

Note: you say "in range `i` to `j`" - in Python, a range is generally not inclusive of `j` and list indexing starts at 0. So, in the above examples, the ouput would be:

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This does not match your example that seems to want to include `j` and start indexing at `1`, which would make your code extremely unpythonic and just wrong from my perspective as a professional software developer. But of course you could easily update the indices if you wanted to match that.

Also note that, the choice of 'range' is yours - for a function like `rev_sublist` I don't think making `j` inclusive is a bad idea - in fact, I'd probably prefer it.

Here's a solution without recursion (using the same convention as above):

```
def rev_sublist(xs, i, j):
    return xs[:i] + xs[j-1:i-1:-1] + xs[j:]
```

Which makes it pretty obvious why a recursive solution is a bad one.

If I were to write this function and the interface wasn't set in stone, I'd probably prefer:

```
def rev_sublist(xs, i, j):
    return xs[:i] + xs[j:i-1:-1] + xs[j+1:]
```

Which would return `[1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9]` for the above example. (also note that it's exactly the same as the solution independently proposed by user @MichaelM. which reinforces the idea that it's the more or less obvious implementation in Python)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use recursion here. Just use the built-in `.reverse()` method for a slice of the original list. You can do it like this:

```
def reverseSlice(lst, i, j):
    return lst[:i] + lst[j:i-1:-1] + lst[j+1:]


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(reverseSlice(lst,  2, 4))  # => [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: The topic is the recursion method. I wanted then to compare it.

Comment: @MalumPhobos I'm not sure that this can be implemented with recursion. If it can, then it would most likely be a worse approach than this.

Comment: You don't need any functions to reverse an Iterable range.  Iterable slices take the same arguments as `range` (start, stop, and increment).  -   `listSlice[j:i-1:-1]`